# How to reset Laravel disk config?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I have multiple s3 storages, that I need to swap during the runtime (I have a cron job that does some job on different s3 disks).

When I set the disk using laravel `config(['filesystems.disks.first' => $config])`, after the disk is set for the first time it can not be changed later and it always sends requests to the same disk.

How can I reset the disk connection?

Answer (score 1):

`config/filesystems.php` will happily permit you to enter *multiple* disks:

```
'disks' => [
    'disk-one' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'bucket' => 'disk-one',
    ],
    'disk-two' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'bucket' => 'disk-two',
    ],
    'disk-three' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'bucket' => 'disk-three',
    ],
```

Which you can switch between easily at runtime:

```
Storage::disk('disk-two')->get('foo');
```

Comment: The number of disks is 40+ and i dont know how many will be in advance, they are stored by users in their records. Maybe there will be 100+ in the future if app gets popular.

Comment: The above is still possible in that scenario. You might also consider using folders *within* a single S3 bucket. Knowing more about your use case might help; I suspect you're running into Laravel's config cache here.